# How to create a unique list of combinations from multiple vectors?

Tags: r

I want to determine how many types of pizzas can be ordered on different breads using 2 different toppings altogether. But I want to create a list of unique combinations.

I have used the combinations() function from the arrangements package to create the list of unique combinations, and I have done that for toppings. I am struggling to figure out how to incorporate crusts.

```
toppings <- c("Pepperoni", "Canadian Bacon", "Sausage", "Italian Sausage")
crust <- c("Thick", "Thin", "Cracker")
toppingcombo <- combinations(toppings)
pizza <- arrangements::combinations(c(crust, toppings), 3)
```

The last line of code is instead showing this as the result.

```
     [,1]    [,2]            
[1,] "Thick" "Thin"          
[2,] "Thick" "Tuscano"       
[3,] "Thick" "Pepperoni"
```

I would like the results to show:

```
     [,1]    [,2]        [,3]            
[1,] "Thick" "Sausage"   "Bacon"         
[2,] "Thick" "Pepperoni" "Sausage
```

But avoid creating duplicates such as "Thick/Bacon/Sausage" since that is the same thing as row [1,] but with the toppings in a different order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make some modifications to your input data to achieve the goal you wanted.

#### Data

```
toppings <- c("Pepperoni", "Canadian Bacon", "Sausage", "Italian Sausage")
crust <- data.frame(crust = c("Thick", "Thin", "Cracker"))

library(arrangements)
topping_combo <- as.data.frame(combinations(toppings, k = 2, n = length(toppings)))
colnames(topping_combo) <- c("topping_1", "topping_2")
```

So now we have two dataframes: `crust` with only one column and three rows, one for each type of crust; `topping_combo` is a 6x2 dataframe which contains all the possible 2-combinations of toppings.

#### Code

The following code offers one possible solution to create a dataframe in which each row is a type of pizza, as you requested. We use the function `crossing` from `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(crust, topping_combo)
```

#### Output

```
     crust      topping_1       topping_2
1    Thick      Pepperoni  Canadian Bacon
2    Thick      Pepperoni         Sausage
3    Thick      Pepperoni Italian Sausage
4    Thick Canadian Bacon         Sausage
5    Thick Canadian Bacon Italian Sausage
6    Thick        Sausage Italian Sausage
7     Thin      Pepperoni  Canadian Bacon
8     Thin      Pepperoni         Sausage
9     Thin      Pepperoni Italian Sausage
10    Thin Canadian Bacon         Sausage
11    Thin Canadian Bacon Italian Sausage
12    Thin        Sausage Italian Sausage
13 Cracker      Pepperoni  Canadian Bacon
14 Cracker      Pepperoni         Sausage
15 Cracker      Pepperoni Italian Sausage
16 Cracker Canadian Bacon         Sausage
17 Cracker Canadian Bacon Italian Sausage
18 Cracker        Sausage Italian Sausage
```

Answer (score 3):

With base R, similar to @RicS's answer, you can make a table of topping combos and cross-join it with crusts in two steps with `expand.grid` and `cbind`:

```
top_combo = t(combn(toppings, 2))
eg = expand.grid(crust = crust, tc = seq_len(nrow(top_combo)))
res = cbind(eg, top_combo[eg$tc, ])

     crust tc              1               2
1    Thick  1      Pepperoni  Canadian Bacon
2     Thin  1      Pepperoni  Canadian Bacon
3  Cracker  1      Pepperoni  Canadian Bacon
4    Thick  2      Pepperoni         Sausage
5     Thin  2      Pepperoni         Sausage
6  Cracker  2      Pepperoni         Sausage
7    Thick  3      Pepperoni Italian Sausage
8     Thin  3      Pepperoni Italian Sausage
9  Cracker  3      Pepperoni Italian Sausage
10   Thick  4 Canadian Bacon         Sausage
11    Thin  4 Canadian Bacon         Sausage
12 Cracker  4 Canadian Bacon         Sausage
13   Thick  5 Canadian Bacon Italian Sausage
14    Thin  5 Canadian Bacon Italian Sausage
15 Cracker  5 Canadian Bacon Italian Sausage
16   Thick  6        Sausage Italian Sausage
17    Thin  6        Sausage Italian Sausage
18 Cracker  6        Sausage Italian Sausage
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider building a list of matrices by passing both vectors into `sapply`, then row bind all elements at the end:

```
pizza_list <- sapply(crust, function(x,y) cbind(x, t(combn(y, m=2))), toppings, simplify=FALSE)

pizza <- do.call(rbind, pizza_list)
colnames(pizza) <- c("Crust", "Toppings1", "Toppings2")

pizza    
#       Crust     Toppings1        Toppings2        
#  [1,] "Thick"   "Pepperoni"      "Canadian Bacon" 
#  [2,] "Thick"   "Pepperoni"      "Sausage"        
#  [3,] "Thick"   "Pepperoni"      "Italian Sausage"
#  [4,] "Thick"   "Canadian Bacon" "Sausage"        
#  [5,] "Thick"   "Canadian Bacon" "Italian Sausage"
#  [6,] "Thick"   "Sausage"        "Italian Sausage"
#  [7,] "Thin"    "Pepperoni"      "Canadian Bacon" 
#  [8,] "Thin"    "Pepperoni"      "Sausage"        
#  [9,] "Thin"    "Pepperoni"      "Italian Sausage"
# [10,] "Thin"    "Canadian Bacon" "Sausage"        
# [11,] "Thin"    "Canadian Bacon" "Italian Sausage"
# [12,] "Thin"    "Sausage"        "Italian Sausage"
# [13,] "Cracker" "Pepperoni"      "Canadian Bacon" 
# [14,] "Cracker" "Pepperoni"      "Sausage"        
# [15,] "Cracker" "Pepperoni"      "Italian Sausage"
# [16,] "Cracker" "Canadian Bacon" "Sausage"        
# [17,] "Cracker" "Canadian Bacon" "Italian Sausage"
# [18,] "Cracker" "Sausage"        "Italian Sausage"
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/BYR85150)

Answer (score 0):

The following uses `dplyr` to create all combinations between the `crust` and `toppings` via `expand`. Then the `toppings` are sorted alphabetically (`topping_1` < `topping_2`) and a `unique` set is extracted.

```
> library(tidyverse)
> df <- data.frame(
  toppings = c(
    'Pepperoni',
    'Canadian Bacon',
    'Sausage',
    'Italian Sausage'
  ),
  crust = c(
    'Thick', 
    'Thin',
    'Cracker',
    NA # to match the number of toppings
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

> pizza <- df %>% expand(
  crust,
  toppings,
  toppings
) %>% transmute(
  crust = crust,
  topping_1 = if_else(
    toppings < toppings1,
    toppings,
    toppings1
  ),
  topping_2 = if_else(
    toppings < toppings1,
    toppings1,
    toppings
  )
) %>% filter(
  !is.na(crust), # Remove no-base pizzas
  topping_1 != topping_2 # Remove double-toppings of the same kind
) %>% unique() # Keep only unique combinations across crust, topping_1 and topping_2

> pizza
# A tibble: 18 x 3
   crust   topping_1       topping_2      
   <chr>   <chr>           <chr>          
 1 Cracker Canadian Bacon  Italian Sausage
 2 Cracker Canadian Bacon  Pepperoni      
 3 Cracker Canadian Bacon  Sausage        
 4 Cracker Italian Sausage Pepperoni      
 5 Cracker Italian Sausage Sausage        
 6 Cracker Pepperoni       Sausage        
 7 Thick   Canadian Bacon  Italian Sausage
 8 Thick   Canadian Bacon  Pepperoni      
 9 Thick   Canadian Bacon  Sausage        
10 Thick   Italian Sausage Pepperoni      
11 Thick   Italian Sausage Sausage        
12 Thick   Pepperoni       Sausage        
13 Thin    Canadian Bacon  Italian Sausage
14 Thin    Canadian Bacon  Pepperoni      
15 Thin    Canadian Bacon  Sausage        
16 Thin    Italian Sausage Pepperoni      
17 Thin    Italian Sausage Sausage        
18 Thin    Pepperoni       Sausage
```